# GWT adding "nullnullnullnullnull" when Creating HTML widget

Tags: html, gwt, html-table

I'm returning a list generated form a csv file in an html table format:

```
<span class="gwt-HTML">
  <div id="productList">
    nullnullnullnullnull
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th>Type Name</th>
        <th>Class Name</th>
        <th>Sub Class Name</th>
        <th>Minor Class Name</th>
        <th>Country Origin</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
```

etc..

Notice the weird nullnullnullnullnull showing up?  This happens when after the html gets converted into the widget:

```
SimplePanel pnl = new SimplePanel();
HTML res = new HTML(result);
pnl.add(res);
RootPanel.get("tableData").add(pnl);
```

The result variable is the html string:

```
  <div id="productList">
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th>Type Name</th>
        <th>Class Name</th>
        <th>Sub Class Name</th>
        <th>Minor Class Name</th>
        <th>Country Origin</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        ...etc
```

I've checked to make sure the result String does not contain the null's.  Anybody have an idea as to why this is happening? Very strange...

Comment: Did you check the encoding of your cvs file? You may not see the null characters in your editor.

Comment: Can you please tell me that what "result" do stand for ? Please provide some more details for that.

Comment: I doubt it has to do with the csv file, I checked the string in the debugger and it looks fine until generates into the GWT HTML object.

Comment: It is adding null values after <div id="productList">, so definitely it is not getting something while parsing it to HTML. Please try something with that. And also try to inspect value of res before it gets add to RootPanel.It should be a small thing. It is just a guess.

Comment: Yes, It turns out it was a parsing error.  I feel dumb.  Thanks for your help!